# Validating JSF view parameter and error message

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF2 page with a view parameter that must be looked up in a database.
On the page the properties of that entity are then displayed.

Now I would like to handle the case where the view parameter is missing/invalid

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{fooBean.id}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{fooBean.init()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

And the `init()` code is as follows:

```
String msg = "";
if (id == null) {
    msg = "Missing ID!";
}
else {
    try {
        entity = manager.find(id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        msg = "No entity with id=" + id;
    }
}
if (version == null) {
    FacesUtils.addGlobalMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, msg);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

Now my problem is that the remaing page is still rendered and I get errors in the application server log saying that entity is null (and therefore some elements are not rendered properly).
I would like only the error message to be displayed.

Should I be returning a String so that a `POST` to an error page is issued?
However if I choose that way, how do I add a custom error message? Passing Strings as view
parameters does not seem like a good idea at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the best thing to do in these cases, is to send an HTTP response with the appropriate error code (**404** for not found/invalid, **403** for forbidden, etc):

Add to your FacesUtils this utility method:

```
public static void responseSendError(int status, String message)
                           throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    facesContext.getExternalContext().responseSendError(status, message);
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

and then, change in your preRenderView listener to:

```
public void init() throws IOException {
    if (id == null || id.isEmpty()) {
        FacesUtils.responseSendError(404, "URL incomplete or invalid!");
    }
    else {
        try {
            entity = manager.find(id);
        } catch (Exception e) { // <- are you sure you want to do that? ;)
            FacesUtils.responseSendError(404, "No entity found!");
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution. Will init() be called multiple times, or does responseSendError() prevent that?

Comment: Well, `init()` is only called once for each time you access the XHTML page where you declared it as a [`preRenderView`](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html) listener. If you postback to the same page (clicking on a `h:commandButton`, for example), it will actually be called again. You can prevent code from executing on postbacks in it, wrapping with: `if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()){ /* stmts go here... */ }`

Comment: Not sure if I answered your question yet... If you wanted to know if `init()` would be called again after executing `responseSendError()`, the answer is no. Unless you are looking for trouble and made a custom error page that declares this same listener. :)